# How can I render such an array

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array:

```
[
  {
    "room": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "NameRoom"
    },
    "users": [
      {
        "userId": "1",
        "userName": "User1",
      },
      {
        "userId": "2",
        "userName": "User12",
      },
      {
        "userId": "3",
        "userName": "User13",
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "room": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "NameRoom2"
    },
    "users": [
      {
        "userId": "4",
        "userName": "User14",
      },
      {
        "userId": "5",
        "userName": "User15",
      },
      {
        "userId": "6",
        "userName": "User16",
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Here is my rendering code

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://site.ru/api/rooms')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson,
            })
            console.log(responseJson[0].users[0].userName) // i get User1
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}


renderItemRooms = ({ item,index }) => (
                <View style = {styles.containerHeader}>
                    <Text style = {styles.dateTitle}>16.04.2020</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.containerMain}>
                    <Text style = {styles.nameTitle}>RoomName</Text>
                    <IconButton
                    style={styles.menuIcon}
                    icon="text"
                    color={'#e7eee6'}
                    size={40}
                    onPress={this._toggleBottomNavigationView}
                    />
                    <BottomSheet
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        onBackButtonPress={this._toggleBottomNavigationView}
                        onBackdropPress={this._toggleBottomNavigationView}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.bottomNavigationView}>
                            <View style={styles.bottomList}>
                                <FlatList
                                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                                    renderItem={this.renderItemUsers}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.bottomButton}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                                    <Text>Connect</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </BottomSheet>
                </TouchableOpacity>    
)
```

How can I display a list of users in the internal render in my code?
And print the names of rooms.
How to iterate through such an array correctly?

I need to output TouchableOpacity with the name of the room, it has a button on the right, when you click it, a modal menu appears, which contains a list of users in this room, how do I do this correctly?
I've already searched the Internet and didn't find a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you have missed something in FlatList, also there many methods to iterate an array. I will give you an example here and hope this helps.

Example:

```js
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={item => item.room.name} {/* item.name is undefined, you need to add room.name */}
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem={this.renderItemUsers}
/>

// And renderItemUsers method

renderItemUsers = ({ item }) => {
    const Users = () => item.users.map(user => <Text key={user.userId}>{user.userName}</Text>)
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Room : {item.room.name}</Text>
            <Users />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: How i can do
renderItemRoom = ({ item }) {
<Text>RoomName<Text>
<FlatList
renderItem={this.renderItemUsers}
/>
}
FlatList in render?

Comment: Well , I don't think you need 2 FlatList in this case, just wrap Users into a ScrollView and you should get the same result and much cleaner code. <ScrollView><Users /></ScrollView>, just need a little styleing and that's it.

Comment: i have a button right from Name room, when i clicked on this button, i can see bottom modal with users in this room, but i see only users from last room

Comment: when the bottom model opens, it shows me everything over the top, it opens as if every room and shows users from it`
`<BottomSheet>
                   <View>
                       <Users/>
                    </View>
</BottomSheet>`